# Why there is no bindQuery equivalent to bindForm in Suave.Forms?

Tags: f#, suave

I'm trying to write a web site with Suave.io and have a form which can be submitted as post or get request. I found an example how to bind form values to dto, But can't find a way how to bind query params to the same dto.

```
let app : WebPart =
  choose
    [ path "/api" >>= GET >>= Binding.bindReq (bindQuery params_form) classify BAD_REQUEST
      path "/api/v2/" >>= POST >>= Binding.bindReq (bindForm params_form) classify BAD_REQUEST
      NOT_FOUND "Found no handlers" ]

startWebServer defaultConfig app
```

Answer (score 2):

As of version  0.32, There is nothing made up. You have to do it on your own :

```
let withMyDTo fSuccess FFailure = 
    request ( fun r -> 
        let myValue1 = r.queryParam "val1"
        let myValue2 = r.queryParam "val2"
        match myValue1,myValue2 with 
        | Choice1Of2(v1),Choice1Of2(v2) -> fSuccess { val1:v1; val2:v2 }
        | _,_ -> FFailure
    )



choose [path "ddd" >>= withMyDTo doThat OhDoThatThen]
```

Comment: it is not an answer to my question, but anyway thanks for info

Comment: the second part is not, but the first was , no?

Comment: Hm I'm not a native english. Probably I cant understand first sentence right. But I expect to see somethng like: YAGNI or is it a bug or feature and some description to WHY I need it to do it some other way.